# AMP removes policy statements from pages

Tags: amp-html

AMP is removing required policy statements from pages. How can I prevent that?

I'm working on a website for a financial institution. They had to remove AMP because it was removing required financial policy statements from pages.

How can I set up AMP so it won't remove required text?

Comment: Could you add any kind of sample to explain details?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Further, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Also learn how to post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).